# ionic 2/3 : Create a starting page for application

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, loading

I want to create a starting page that show the logo and appear for 2 second before show the app's content, can some one show me the right way to do that ? thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the native ionic splash screen component:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/splash-screen/

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create a new page that'll be presented as the app starts and inside that page you'll do relevant code that is needed for the app to start functioning.

Since i don't know if you're using lazy loaded pages or not i'll leave the page creation to the point where you can fully use that page all up to you.

So in your CLI create a new page with `ionic g page yourPage`

In your `app.components.ts` you'll first point to that created page

**app.components.ts:**

```
export class MyApp {
    rootPage: any = 'YourPage'; // YOUR PAGE WILL BE THE ROOT PAGE FOR NOW

    constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            statusBar.styleDefault();
            splashScreen.hide();
        });
    }
}
```

In your created page you'll do the following:

**yourPage.ts:**

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){}
// USING A LIFECYCLE HOOK TO EXECUTE CODE AFTER THE PAGE IS FULLY LOADED
ionViewDidLoad(){
  setTimeout(()=> {
    // YOU'LL SET THE ROOT WITH THE HOME PAGE YOU NEED TO SHOW AFTER YOU START. DON'T PUSH THE PAGE SINCE YOU DON'T NEED THE USER TO NAVIGATE BACK TO IT.
    // You can also do other relevant code here, like check if the user is logged or not before seting the root to the right page.
    this.navCtrl.setRoot('YourMainHomePage'); 
  }, 2000)
}
```

An in yourPage html code you'll have just the image:

**yourPage.html**

```
<!-- REMOVE HEADER -->
<ion-content padding>
  <img src="path/to/image" alt="my company" />
</ion-content>
```

Hope this helps